# Persistance of expanded detail Jquery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have an asp.net web application that has the option to provide pseudo-realtime data about an automation machine. I am using the JQuery Datatables with an ajax datasource. I have an interval that reloads the data source every set amount of time (which updates my datatable asynchronously from the db) and then redraws the table.

I am also using the responsive plug in for the table, so the web app can be accessed well from phone sized devices. I have set this up so that it drops all of the columns but the first(primary) column and adds the other columns a child (detail) record. This is where my app breaks and my phone users loose usability. This is because whenever the table redraws detail records snaps close. Therefore if a phone user is looking at the table and has expanded the detail of a record the record will snap shut as soon as the table is redrawn.

My solution would be to capture the opened detail and then at the time of redraw re-open the detail. I believe I have captured the detail successfully but everything I have found to try to programmatically expand it has not worked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var row;
        var tr;
        var table = $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
            autoWidth: false,
            processing: false,
            stateSave: true,
            sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetDropData", "Drops")',

            "columns":
            [
                { "width": "10%" },
                { "width": "50%" },
                { "width": "40%" }
            ]
        });

        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            table.ajax.reload(null, false);
        }, 1000);

        //flag is used to determine if last click expanded a detail
        var flag = false;

        //If table is clicked find closest 'tr'
        table.on('click', 'tr', function () {
            tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            row = table.row(tr);

            //was click a detail expansion
            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                flag = true;
            }
        })

        // event fires after ajax call completes (reload and redraw)
        $('#myDataTable').on('xhr.dt', function () {
            if (flag) {
                $(tr).addClass('row_selected');
            }
        });
    });
```

If you can tell why the detail isn't expanded or a better way solution please let me know. I do have a temporary solution in place that just pauses the interval when the detail button is clicked but this makes my phone users table not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Datatables 1.9 and earlier use [`fnDrawCallback()`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks).

If you're using Datatables 1.10+ use [`drawCallback`()](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback).

Both of these callbacks go in your datatables initializer and can take your row detail opening code.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
       //open detail row here
    }
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I don't think my issue is event based. Right now I have an event that triggers whenever the database is reloaded and redrawn (with the xhr event), which I think is accomplishing the same thing.  My main problem is interacting with Datatables detail code. I've scoured the internet and the datatables js and can't figure out how I should actually write the open detail code (I've tried several things).

Comment: If I understand correctly after each redraw event you want to reopen any previously open detail rows, right? If you're already tracking the open ones like you said you can use the drawCallback to restore the state. You should be able to loop over all the TRs and expand accordingly. I've done this in scenarios where I want every detail row to be open by default.

Comment: Thank You! It would appear that the xhr event wasn't triggering them for what ever reason. But I implemented this callback and it worked!